# Spring Aop XML Error

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, aop

I am learning Apring AOP. I have setup the eclipse for spring AOP, but still i am getting an error in XML file (spring.xml). the Error is in the line No 10 of spring.xml file. means it is not considering **aop:aspectj-autoproxy** tag . rest configuration is correct because i am able to run some basic programs, so please suggest me what to do, either i missed some jar or something else ??

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://springframework.org/schema/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean name="triangle" class="org.spring.model.Triangle">
    <property name="name" value="Triangle name" />
</bean>

<bean name="circle" class="org.spring.model.Circle">
    <property name="name" value="Circle name" />
</bean>

<bean name="shapeservice" class="org.spring.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName"/>

<bean name="loggingaspect" class="org.spring.aspect.LoggingAspect"/>
```

**Errors**

```
Apr 21, 2016 11:56:55 AM   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b1a58a3:  startup date [Thu Apr 21 11:56:55 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 21, 2016 11:56:55 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:aspectj-autoproxy'.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.spring.aop.AopMain.main(AopMain.java:10)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:aspectj-autoproxy'.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two schema locations http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
http://springframework.org/schema/spring-context-2.5.xsd

with

http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

Comment: Which version of Spring you are using, if possible share the pom.xml

Comment: spring framework version - 3.2.0 ( i am unable to find pom.xml ?) - @Dileep

Comment: Make sure you have spring aop and Spring aspects jars in your classpath

Comment: yes, They exist  (org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy) - but aop:aspectj-autoproxy  tag in not enable ?? @Dileep